Windows Batch - How do I create an array with a unique set of values?
I'm messing around in Batch and writing code that loops through files in a directory and adds the last four characters of the file name to an array.  The problem is that there are duplicates in my array.  Is there a way to only add the value to an array if it doesn't exist yet?
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set i=0
for %%f in (*00.DIF) do (
  set fname=%%~nf
  set year=!fname:~-4!
  ::echo !year!
  set Obj[!i!].name=!year!
  set /a i=!i!+1
)
set lastindex=!i!

for /L %%f in (0,1,!lastindex!) do ( 
  echo !Obj[%%f].name!
)


Let's be honest.  Even if you can make this work, it's never going to be maintainable.  The lines look like random noise, and when you come back to it six weeks later, you won't recognize it.  Once you get to this point, you should be using a scripting language:  Python, Perl, Ruby, LUA. or even bash.

set Obj[ | findstr /e "=!year! && ( echo !year! already exists ) || ( echo unique !year! ). replace the echo commands with the functionality you want. ATTENTION: replace :: with REM. :: is a (invalid) label which causes unexpected behaviour (like skipping lines). @Tim: the code is easily readable. There is no "best" language. Often the "best" is what you're most used to (if it can do the job, that is)

@TimRoberts - Batch is a scripting language. Just because you can't understand it doesn't mean it's incomprehensible (although on a related note, it's hilarious that you'd recommend Perl and Ruby). Every single one of those lines can be easily understood by someone with even a passing knowledge of the language.

(or ... | findstr /elc:"].name=!year!" ... if .name hints that there might be other obj[...].<anythingElse>'s)

I apologize up front for my ignorance, the code you see above is after a day's worth of googling.  @Stephan, I'm trying to figure out how to apply your code and so far, I've come up with this but it's not echo-ing anything of value.  It just says "Obj[0].name=K900" over and over.  K900 is one of the "year" values.

It's very odd that all of your filenames end with *2000.DIF, *1900.DIF, *1800.DIF, *1700.DIF etc. Hold on, I just saw your above comment; your years have alphabet characters in them!


As already noted, within a block statement (a parenthesised series of statements), REM statements rather than the broken-label remark form (:: comment) should be used because labels terminate blocks, confusing cmd. :: is a broken label because you cannot reach :: with a goto, but it's a label nonetheless.

Use set "var=value" for setting string values - this avoids problems caused by trailing spaces. Don't assign " or a terminal backslash or Space. Build pathnames from the elements - counterintuitively, it is likely to make the process easier. Use set /a var=value to set numeric values.

I prefer to avoid ADFNPSTXZ (in either case) as metavariables (loop-control variables)
ADFNPSTXZ are also metavariable-modifiers which can lead to difficult-to-find bugs
(See for/f from the prompt for documentation)

The !var! syntax is only required to access the modified value of var where var is varied within the code block (parenthesised sequence of commands).


Hence, rewritten code:
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /A i=0
SET "chosen="
REM for %%e in (*00.DIF) do (
for %%e in (1234 0011 4567 7890 0011 4183) do (
  set fname=%%~ne
  set year=!fname:~-4!
  REM echo !year!
  set Obj[!i!].name=!year!
  set /a i+=1
  SET "unaltered=Y"
  FOR %%y IN (!chosen!) DO IF DEFINED unaltered IF "%%y"=="!year!" (
  SET "unaltered="
   set /a i-=1
   set "Obj[!i!].name="
  )
  IF DEFINED unaltered SET "chosen=!year! !chosen!"
)
set /a lastindex=i-1

for /L %%e in (0,1,%lastindex%) do ( 
  echo !Obj[%%e].name!
)
GOTO :EOF

New variable chosen is set to nothing.
I've replaced your first for loop with a loop that simply processes a series of numbers for testing purposes. I've also change the metavariable throught from f to e.
Use more modern syntax to increment i. see set/? from the prompt or endless SO items for docco.
New loop on %%y to search chosen for previously-assigned values. Note the use of unaltered as a Boolean - It's either defined as Y or undefined. If it's defined, simply reverse the increment of i and delete the "array" string-value assigned. Using Boolean
Then, if the value in year is new, unaltered is defined and the new value of year is appended to the list of values in chosen.
After the entire list is processed, lastindex is set to i - 1 since i points to the next element to be filled.
--- edit -----
Having recaffienated, using Stephan's findstr idea...
@ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /A i=0
SET "chosen="
REM for %%e in (*00.DIF) do (
for %%e in (1234 0011 4183 4567 7890 0011 7890 7890 7890 4183) do (
  set fname=%%~ne
  set year=!fname:~-4!
  REM echo !year!
  ECHO !year!|FINDSTR ": !chosen!"  >NUL
  IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
   set Obj[!i!].name=!year!
   set /a i+=1
   SET "chosen=!year! !chosen!"
  )
)
set /a lastindex=i-1

for /L %%e in (0,1,%lastindex%) do ( 
  echo !Obj[%%e].name!
)
GOTO :EOF

Here, if year is not in the string chosen then findstr will set errorlevel to 1; if it is then errorlevel will be set to 0.
findstr by default will find any of the space-separated strings, but it doesn't like an empty string, so a colon is added to the list as a dummy; a colon is impossible in the name part of a filename.
Only if yesr is missing from the list will it be added.
We don't need the actual output of findstr, just that it sets errorlevel, so the output is sent to nowhere by the >nul.

This runs like a dream!  Thanks!
What exactly does (1234 0011 4567 7890 0011 4183) do?
Also, thank you for the detail.  I'm going to read it over and over again until it makes sense, LOL!

That line simply sets %%e to those strings in sequence for testing purposes so that I don't have to create *00.dif files to test the routine. Just delete that line and un-REMark the (altered) original to process your filenames instead.

You have not specified if the order of array elements is important. If not, then there is a very simple way to solve your problem: Instead of use a numeric index, use the value as the index!
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for %%f in (*00.DIF) do (
  set fname=%%~nf
  set year=!fname:~-4!
  REM echo !year!
  set Obj[!year!].name=!year!
)

REM Show array elements
for /F %%a in ('set Obj[') do ( 
  echo %%a
)

Because can not be more than one element with the same index, then don't matters if the same element is defined more than one time. At end, just one element with such an index exists.
PS - Why you named Obj[#].name the array? It is very unusual because the "name" part dont appears in the values. IMHO a better name could be Year[#]
